# Compile Lua from source and create C module with it

Tags: c, lua

I thought of compiling Lua from source code and then create a C module.
I compiled Lua with success but I can't build my C module.

So, I compiled Lua like this:

```
gcc -o Lua *.c -Os -std=c99
```

Compiled my module like this:

```
gcc -Wall -shared -fPIC -o module.so -I. module.c
```

But there are a few errors here:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_lua_pushcclosure", referenced from:
      _luaopen_module in module-fb0b1f.o
  "_lua_pushnumber", referenced from:
      _super in module-fb0b1f.o
  "_lua_setglobal", referenced from:
      _luaopen_module in module-fb0b1f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see  invocation)
```

The C module itself:

```
#include "lua.h"


static int super(lua_State* L) {
    lua_pushnumber(L, 5);
    return 1;
}

int luaopen_module(lua_State* L) {
    lua_register(L, "super", super);
    return 0;
}
```

My Lua script:

```
require("module")
print(super())
```

I'm on Unix based system (Mac), but I want it to work on Linux as well.

Edit:

Problem to compile C module was fixed by entering `-bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup` instead of `-shared` (Thanks lhf).
But I can't import the module in Lua.

```
> require("module")
error loading module 'module' from file './module.so':
    dynamic libraries not enabled; check your Lua installation
```

Another thing:
This seems to be a quick fix only; `-bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup`. This does not work on Linux. How can I do this on linux? I wanted a solution for Unix based systems.

Comment: Try `-bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup` instead of `-shared`.

Comment: Awesome, I can now build the C module. But I can't import it in Lua.

Answer (score 2):

- Download Lua from [lua.org](https://www.lua.org) and build Lua with `make macosx`. See [Getting started](https://www.lua.org/start.html#installing).
- Use `-bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup` instead of `-shared` to build `module.so`.
- Use `require"module"` to load it into Lua.
- Call `super`.

Make sure you're running the `lua` program that you have built above, not some other version that is installed.

Comment: So I did. And I could build C module, but not include it in the Lua script.

Comment: I want to build it myself, without MakeFile.

Comment: @Azinum use `-DLUA_USE_MACOSX` when building Lua.

Comment: Without the MakeFile?